# Is constexpr useful for overload

Tags: c++, constexpr

Is there a way in c++ to get a different overload called based on the runtime/compile time constness of an input? My version(12) of MSVC can't do this using constexpr.  Reading c++ documentation, I am not sure if this is the way constexpr works.

```
inline int Flip4(constexpr int n) {
    return ((n & 0xFF) << 24) | ((n & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((n & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((n & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}
inline int Flip4(int n) {
    return _byteswap_ulong(n);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a = Flip4('abcd');  // calc at compile time
    int b = Flip4(argc);  // calc at runtime
}
```

So if this can be done, how?  I think there might be a way to use template deduction to do it, but I can't figure out how.

EDIT

I came up with this, but am not sure why it works, && is still fuzy for me, and not sure if this works for everything.

```
template<class T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int>::type
inline Flip4(T&& n) {
    //cout << "compile time" << endl;
    return ((n & 0xFF) << 24) | ((n & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((n & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((n & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}
template<class T> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int>::type
inline Flip4(T&& n) {
    //cout << "run time" << endl;
    return _byteswap_ulong(n);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = Flip4(argc);
    n += Flip4(1);
    return n;
}
```

If you compile without commenting out the output, it produces this output.

```
run time
compile time
```

and it produces this assembly, which is what I want:

```
int n = Flip4(argc);
000000013FA11270  bswap       ecx  
n += Flip4(1);
000000013FA11272  lea         eax,[rcx+1000000h]
```

Are there cases of integer T where this won't work?

Comment: No, there are no `constexpr` parameters.

Comment: How can i do something like this.

Comment: How about changing the first "overload" to somthing like `template <int n> inline int Flip4() { ... }` and then calling it with `Flip4<0xc0de>()` ?

Comment: Are you trying to use an intrinsic or assembly at compile time?

Comment: @865719.  That wont work for Flip4<n>().  I'd like to make a library function that can make use of template metaprogramming if the argument is a constant, or call a slow runtime equivalent if not.

Comment: @Jason Say I have legacy code that calls Flip4('1234') and Flip4(n).  Right now I use the first Flip4 func since a compile time const is the most common case.  Unfortunately if the input is a runtime variable, then that code is not optimal.  Instead I want to use the intrinsic.  The issue is creating a single function that overloads based on n being a compile time constant or not.

Comment: Clang will compile the above into the single `bswap` instruction (even a generalized one).  If you can use clang you could just define it as a `constexpr` function, but I'm not sure that helps in this scenario.

Comment: @Jason So will gcc actually, according to [this](http://gcc.godbolt.org).

Comment: I don't want to use bswap if the value is a runtime const, as that would be slower than just calculating FLIP the slow way and letting the compiler work it out at compile time.

Comment: @johnnycrash If you leave it at your first version (the one with shifts, but without constexpr), both gcc and clang will generate one bswap for runtime and nothing for compile time - just the actual resulting value. Not sure what will it do with `_byteswap_ulong`. Check your compiler assembly output.

Comment: Just checked - VS2015 computes the value for constant input also during compile time when you use `_byteswap_ulong`. So all is good - no actual need for `constexpr` at all. The assembly for the code in the link in my previous comment (but using `_byteswap_ulong` instead of shifts) is `bswap       ecx` and `lea         eax,[rcx+64636261h]`.

Comment: Clang and recent versions of GCC should compute the values at compile time and emit `bswap` for non-const values with `Flip4` only defined as `constexpr`.  According to @Rostislav, MSVC '15 can evaluate the constants with the intrinsic at compile time as well.

Comment: @Rostislav Ahhh well knowing vs2015 does that is nice!

Comment: I added a template version of Flip4 which seems to work, but I'm sure it has issues.  I am going to not worry about it for _byteswap_xxx, but I still need a working technique like this for other similar situations.  I am not sure if my solution is good though.

Comment: I am feeling stupid.  I looked at the disassembly for _byteswap_ulong(10) and vs2013 correctly computes the value at runtime!  I still would like to figure out how to do this with overloading though!

Comment: Oh i remember now what happened.  I was using Flip4 in a case statement and it doesn't like the intrinsic.  When I get to vs2015 I should be able to put constexpr in front of my second templated version and have it succeed there, right?

Comment: From what @Rostislav described, you shouldn't even need the `constexpr` with VS '15.  I do know Clang will eagerly evaluate functions at compile time without `constexpr` as part of constant folding, but I can't personally verify anything else.

Comment: Would constexpr allow you to use Flip4(n) in a case statement?  "case Flip4(42):"

Comment: @johnnycrash I don't understand how your compile-time function can print out "compile time"? std::cout is run-time. How can compile-time function use cout?
Are you sure it is really compile-time?

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` can only be applied to variables and functions, but not function parameters (details on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)). Furthermore, you cannot overload the function on whether it is computed at compile or run-time, i.e. this is not valid:

```
constexpr int Flip4(int n) {
    return ((n & 0xFF) << 24) | ((n & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((n & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((n & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}

inline int Flip4(int n) {
    return _byteswap_uint64(n);
}
```

One way is to give the functions different names and call them accordingly.

Just as a side note,

> A `constexpr` specifier used in a function declaration implies `inline`.

So you don't need to declare your `constexpr` function `inline`

Also, don't forget that `constexpr` functions are only *guaranteed* to be evaluated at compile-time if they are used in a context required at compile time. So to force it you would need to write:

```
 constexpr int a = Flip4('abcd');
```

Comment: You could use a defaulted argument `bool compile_time = true`, and then call `Flip4(stuff, false)` to invoke the runtime version explicitly.

Comment: @melak47 Yeah - there are many different ways to achieve this. Changed the wording :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the implied inline note.  I didn't know that!

Comment: I have to reasons for needing overload resolution.  1) How shall we say it... unsophisticated developers, and 2) legacy code.

Comment: @johnnycrash Yeah, got it from your other comments. See my last comment to the original post - perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is illegal.

> [C++11, dcl.constexpr] The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only
>   to the definition of a variable, the declaration of a function or
>   function template, or the declaration of a static data member of a
>   literal type (3.9). *...* [ *Note:* Function parameters cannot be
>   declared constexpr. — *end note* ]

`constexpr` doesn't even exist in MSVC 2013, so you couldn't try it even if you wanted to. Also, if you're wondering why the feature isn't allowed, see [constexpr overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936549/constexpr-overloading).

Comment: Note that in the linked answer, I provided an argument against the particular intended use (string pooling) of `constexpr`-overloading, and not against the hypothetical feature in general.

Comment: Its a problem for me since I can only speed up runtime constant or non runtime constant cases, but not both - unless I create 2 different functions.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, you can try this to work around the limitation you're facing:

<kbd>**[Run It Online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4917b5eb728d1925)**</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <int n>
constexpr int Flip4() {
    return ((n & 0xFF) << 24) | ((n & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((n & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((n & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}
inline int Flip4(int n) {
    return _byteswap_ulong(n);
}

int main() {
    constexpr int a = Flip4<0xabcd>();  // calc at compile time
    int b = Flip4(0xabcd);  // calc at runtime

    static_assert(a == -844431360, "");

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
}
```

**EDIT**: Don't lose hope! [User-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) are here to the rescue :)

<kbd>**[Run It Online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ae67992463ca711)**</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// wraps a single integer (unsigned long long) in order to use it in a user-defined literal
// the type (unsigned long long) is a limitation of the standard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596909/865719
struct IntegerWrapper
{
    const unsigned long long value;
    constexpr explicit IntegerWrapper(unsigned long long val) : value{val} {}
};
// user-defined literal
constexpr IntegerWrapper operator "" _iw (const unsigned long long value) 
{ 
    return IntegerWrapper{value};
}

constexpr int Flip4(IntegerWrapper&& n) {
    return ((n.value & 0xFF) << 24) | ((n.value & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((n.value & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((n.value & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}

inline int Flip4(int n) {
    return _byteswap_ulong(n);
}

int main() {

    constexpr int a = Flip4(0xabcd_iw);  // calc at compile time
    const     int b = Flip4(0xabcd);     // calc at runtime

    static_assert(a == -844431360, "");

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but I want to use some sort of overload resolution so I don't have 2 functions.

Comment: That is cool.  But still you have to do something different to call both versions.  Check out my edit to my