# How can I give a compile error if the function is evaluated at compile time and a runtime exception otherwise?

Tags: c++, constants, metaprogramming

If I have a constexpr function that can raise an exception at runtime, I want to make it able to give a compile error if it's evaluated at compile time.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr void func (const int x)
{
    if (x == 0) {
        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            /// compile error
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("x cannot be 0.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried putting `static_assert` inside the if statement, but it evaluates it regardless of the if statement (since the if is not constexpr I'm assuming). I have also tried `static_assert(x != 0);`, but it tells me `non-constant condition for static assertion` (which makes some sense...?).

Is there any (preferably easy) way to do this? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I generalized the function, in my case I have a constructor that I need to use to generate both compile time and run time objects. So I would like the program to give a compile error with a message like `x cannot be 0` if I try to create a constexpr object with x being 0.

Comment: you are missing a `}` and adding the includes makes it simpler for others to compile your code

Comment: This seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39742883/8658157), which would imply that there's no solution.

Comment: you cannot raise a compiler error depending on a runtime variable `x`

Comment: is making `x` a template argument an option?

Comment: Did you try just removing the check and throwing at compile time?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to a compilation error if this is evaluated in a context requiring a constant expression, then just throwing is sufficient. Otherwise, whether or not a function is evaluated at compile time is up to the compiler and there isn't really anything you can do to force it not to evaluate at compile-time (how would you observe the difference anyway?).

Comment: @user17732522 Just throwing really generates an error, but the error message is misleading since it is not related to the invalid argument: https://godbolt.org/z/vsP189KaT

Comment: @DanielLangr Of course it is up to the compiler whether it will give details on why the expression is not a constant expression, but using an array length is an atypical example since GCC supports VLAs and therefore doesn't produce the same diagnostic it would in other situations that require a constant expression, see e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/YTj9ooaqf. Except making the expression not a constant expression, there is no way to cause a compilation failure based on the evaluation of the function. Mechanism are throwing, calling a non-`constexpr` function, etc.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I generalized the example, but basically I have this: the function is a constructor for a class. If I create a constexpr object and give it x = 0, I want to generate a compile error, but if the object is not constexpr, I want it to throw. I will add this in the question.

Comment: @Artyer I can do that, but it doesn't generate the error that I want, instead it says that `throw` is not a constant expression. Which kinda works I guess, since it compiles if `x` is not 0, but I would rather have a more concise message. `expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant expression` does not say much.